# Beginner Python Game. Create records file

Tags: python-2.7, save, records

I am learning Python and did this little game where you try to guess the number the Computer has generated.

```
from random import randint


def guess():
    play = 0    
    while play != 'exit':    
        numbercomp = randint(1, 9)
        tries = 0
        humanno = 0    
        while numbercomp != humanno:
            humanno = int(raw_input("What is my number, from 1 to 9? "))

            if numbercomp == humanno:
                tries = tries + 1
                print('you are right, nice!')

            elif numbercomp < humanno:
                tries = tries + 1
                print('my number is smaller than yours')

            else:
                tries = tries + 1
                print('my number is bigger than yours')

        print 'you got it in', tries, 'tries'
        play = raw_input('press any key to play , type "exit" to leave')
    print "Good bye!"
    exit()


while True:
    try:
        guess()

    except ValueError:
        print('that was not a number from 1 to 9!')
```

I wonder what would be a way to save the best score (less tries) and the name of the holder into a file and have the program show this information up every time it starts. Less important would be making this file encrypted in some way.

Also, if you spot that the could would be done in a more elegant fashion I would appreciate feedback.

Comment: You could save the results in something like a dictionary and then use `pickle` to save that dictionary. Then every time the program starts, it loads the pickle file and displays the contents of the dictionary

Comment: Your code is very well laid out and readable by the way. I wouldn't be able to tell you're a beginner :)

Comment: Only other thing I would say is that the positioning of the `try` `except` block is problematic. If a user enters something that is not a number, the program will run `guess()` again and therefore choose a new number to guess!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I try to learn right from the beginning! I will try the Dictionary and pickle method. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance something you could is like this

```
if tries > score:
            pickle.dump( favorite_color, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
```

If the trys are lower than the high score then it changes the highest score.

then to open it just do

```
highscore = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
```

and you can just print the high score when the function is first ran.

Comment: It's fine I'm sure you will get it.